# C# SqlMethods Like Not Working

Tags: c#, linq

I'm brand new to using Linq and can't get the SqlMethods.Like function work.

Here's my simplified example:

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        mylist.Add("100");
        mylist.Add("101");
        mylist.Add("102");
        mylist.Add("103");
        mylist.Add("104");
        mylist.Add("105");
        mylist.Add("106");
        mylist.Add("107");

        var filtered = mylist.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x, "10%"));
        foreach (var record in filtered)
        {
            textBox1.Text += record + "\n";
        }
```

My variable called filtered comes back empty. What am I missing?

If I use x.Equals("100") I get results back.

Comment: The methods are like totally like not working! ;)

Comment: You are doing an in-memory filtering. SqlMethods are meant for Linq-2-Sql scenarios.

Comment: Yep. Not linq to sql... use x.StartsWith instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx)

> Determines whether a specific character string matches a specified
>   pattern. This method is currently only supported in LINQ to SQL
>   queries.

Your query is not a LINQ to SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

In your case use:

```
var filtered = mylist.Where(x => x.Contains("10"));
```

Comment: Typically you use String.StartsWith/EndsWith/Contains

Comment: :) Yes. Just to have the LINQ flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use **Contains** for example

```
var filtered = mylist.Where(x => x.Contains("10"));
```

If you ***really*** want SQL `LIKE`, you can use [`System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx), which LINQ-to-SQL maps to `LIKE` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains operator` instead Like